# How do I hide a password

Tags: c++, input, passwords

so I am new to C++ and was wondering how to hide a password entry in a console application, this is the current script but everything i lookup never works.

```
string password;
cout << "Password: "; 
cin >> password;
```

so instead of
Password: MyPassword
it would be
Password: **********

Comment: The input you see typed on the screen is a function of the shell program you're interacting with. What operating system/shell is this supposed to run on?

Comment: I am trying to do this with Visual Studio on windows